# Difference between NSLog and Printf statement for ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printf, nslog

I want to know about the difference between the `NSLog` and the `Printf` statement in Objective-C (for application purpose...!)

Why do all developer use `NSLog` instead of `Printf` ?

Both look similar, but what is the difference in internal working?

At which point can they be differentiated ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- `printf()` is a C standard library function, accepting a C string constant (`const char *`) as its format argument. `printf()` writes to stdout.
- `NSLog()` is a Foundation function, accepting a constant NSString as format, and has an extended format specifier set (for example, `printf()` does't print objects specified by `%@`, `NSLog()` does).
  `NSLog()` also prints the process name and date before it prints the actual format and writes to sdterr.

Basically, we can say that `NSLog()` is an extended `printf()`
Style function for Objective-C (more precisely, Cocoa and Cocoa Touch) and specific purposes.

Answer (score 26):

NSLog is like a printf, but it does a bit more:

- A timestamp is added to the output.
- The output is sent to the Xcode console, or whatever stderr is defined as.
- It accepts all the printf specifiers, but it also accepts the `@` operator for objects which  displays the string provided by the object's `description` method. (`description` is part of NSObject, so all objects can override it to return a string that describes the object).
- The output is also sent to the Apple System Log (ASL), which is Apple's version of syslogd. This data can be read by other applications using a C API, or by a OS X user using the application “Console”.

Comment: Question, is this Apple System Log synonymous with [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) which appears to use the `os_log` construct.

Comment: Apparently they're distinct as it turns out http://blog.safedk.com/technology/nslog-os_log-multiple-ios-versions/. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/migrating-to-unified-logging-swift-edition/

Answer (score 9):

From a developer point of view, the biggest difference is that NSLog supports Objective-C object types via the %@ format. NSLog also writes to stderr, while printf writes to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

I see two main differences between `NSLog` and `printf`:

1. `NSLog` supports `NSString` objects through the `%@` extension;
2. furthermore, `NSLog` automatically adds time and process data (e.g., 2012-01-25 17:52:10.479 process[906:707])

Comment: More accurately: `NSLog supports objects through the %@ extension, by implicitly calling that object's -(NSString*) description; method`

Comment: The third biggest difference is that NSLog sends output to stderr, where as printf sends to stdout.