# Input/ Output alternatives for printf/scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

It may sound strange that knowing a lot about iOS and having some experience in .net, I am a newcomer to C. Somewhere I got this target to find average of n numbers without using `printf` and `scanf`. I don't want the code for the program but I am seeking alternatives to the mentioned functions.

Is code with `printf/scanf` required here? Also do let me know if my query stands invalid.

Comment: This might get you started.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006801/difference-between-nslog-and-printf-statement-for-objectivec

Hope it helps.

Comment: "It may sound strange that knowing a lot about iOS I am a newcomer to C." - It does, indeed. In general iOS development is done using Objective-C which is a superset of C - if you do iOS development, you should already be more than experienced in C.

Comment: @H2CO3 : I have been fully dedicated to Iphone programming. If my query links to this, I am bad programmer. Thanks for your opinion though :)

Comment: I think the more interesting question would be to find average of n numbers using `printf` & `scanf`. I never knew these functions could do math.

Comment: @Nitish Actually, I'm not saying you would be a bad programmer - I'm just saying that you should really know C (and the standard library) forwards and backwards beforehand :)

Comment: @user93353 : These will do no math. If used, they will input, output data.

Comment: So basically your question is how to do input & output of numbers without using `printf` & `scanf`.

Comment: @H2CO3 : I totally understand. It is really unfortunate part of me that I started with IOS, but someway fortunate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, neither `printf` nor `scanf` is really needed for this.

The obvious alternatives would be to read the input with something like `getc` or `fgets` and convert from characters to numbers with something like `strtol`.

On the output side, you'd more or less reverse that, converting from numbers to characters (e.g., with `itoa` which is quite common, though not actually standard), then printing out the resulting string (e.g., with fputs).

Comment: Thanks Jerry, will try this and let you know.

Comment: If `sprintf` is allowed, you can use it instead of `itoa` cos it's standard. And of course, if `C++` is allowed, then use ostringstream.