# remove timestamp and process id

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use code for show user number in debug. How to remove in only debug line `2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628]`

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"user %d", i);
}
```

in debug I want to get

```
user1 
user2
user3
```

and etc

But get this

```
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628] user1
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628] user2
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628] user3
```

How I can remove this lines

```
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628] 
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628]
2016-08-20 13:02:52.773 1[37441:2806628]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` instead of `NSLog`:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
 { 
   printf("User=%d\n",i); //Here \n is for new line
 }
```

[Difference between NSLog and Printf statement for ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006877/4078527)

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead of `NSLog`. Because `NSLog` prints logs like `time stamp` and other details like process name.

If you want every word in new line then add `\n` in `printf` function.

There are basic major difference between `printf` and `NSLog` but this is beyond the requirement that asked in question. so, as you asked that you don't want `timestamp and process id` then you should use `printf` instead of `NSLog`. That's it!!

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use `printf` function instead of `NSLog` like this because `NSLog` also print project name and `timestamp` with it.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("\nUser %d",i);
}
```

**Note:** `printf` also used to print the formatted sting just like we used in `c` language also you need to use `\n` to set every print statement in new line.